# Encryption-decryption between Ruby and Dot net

Tags: c#, ruby, encryption

I need tyhe dot net equivalent of the following code. Matter is, I am encrypting using Ruby on client side, here is the code. 
The encoded string will be passed to a C# web service. That has to decrypt the string.

If someone can provide the dot net equivalent of this code, then it will be helpful.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ezcrypto'
require 'crypt/rijndael'

plaintext = '24.9195N 17.821E'


aes_key = Crypt::Rijndael.new('0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef')
aes_cyphertext = aes_key.encrypt_string(plaintext)
print "\n"

print aes_cyphertext +"\n"

print Base64.encode64(aes_cyphertext)
print "\n"

print aes_key.decrypt_string(aes_cyphertext)
print "\n"
```

Comment: I'm a C# developer just learning Ruby so I find your question interesting and tried to run your code. But I always get the following error. How is this?
  irb(main):009:0> aes_cyphertext = aes_key.encrypt_string(plaintext)
  NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for 48:Fixnum

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be something like this code shown below as a unit test.  The first part does the encryption - the second half does the decryption.

Paste the code into a new MSTest unit test (Create New Test Project or add to an existing one).

The key and the iv are what you'll need to set accordingly.

```
//needed to convert from hex string
public static byte[] FromHexString(string hexString)
{
  int NumberChars = hexString.Length;
  byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
  return bytes;
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
  string toEncryptString = "24.9195N 17.821E";
  //initialise key and IV (note - all zero IV is not recommended!)
  byte[] key = FromHexString("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef");
  byte[] iv = FromHexString("00000000000000000000000000000000");
  byte[] toEncrypt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncryptString);

  byte[] cipherBytes = null;
  string cipherText = null;

  //encrypt
  using (System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael r = new RijndaelManaged())
  {
    r.Key = key;
    r.IV = iv;
    using(System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform transform 
      = r.CreateEncryptor())
    {
      using (var mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
      {
        using (var cStream = 
          new CryptoStream(mStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
          cStream.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
          cStream.FlushFinalBlock();
          cipherBytes = mStream.ToArray();
          cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //decrypt
  byte[] toDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
  string decryptedString = null;
  using (System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael r = new RijndaelManaged())
  {
    r.Key = key;
    r.IV = iv;
    using(System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform transform2
      = r.CreateDecryptor()) // <-- difference here
    {
      using (var mStream2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
      {
        using (var cStream2 = 
          new CryptoStream(mStream2, transform2, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
          cStream2.Write(toDecrypt, 0, toDecrypt.Length);
          cStream2.FlushFinalBlock();
          decryptedString = 
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mStream2.ToArray());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Assert.AreEqual(toEncryptString, decryptedString);
}
```

Comment: Hi, But my problem still persists. actually i am not trying enc-decryption in dot net. the encryption is done thru this code in ruby, as shown above. the decyption has to be done in C#. thats where the problem is. if i pass the ruby-encrypted string to this function, then I get an exception. Secondly, the rubyt encrypted string is I/KHlflomjFprrySknfNN1D9QGjSYLR724GDF1yPw0wi2fGlxoudTc/CvfaQwJPF, whereas dot net encrypted string is V0if2VhxaEbTj4w4SEDBYKSSl0DxmLH/1zgZxjrfonM=

Comment: The ruby code is probably using a random IV - in which case you have no hope of being able to decrypt it because you need to know both the key and the IV in order for it to work.  You can use the decryption code to perform the decryption - I'm not saying you have to do both in C# - just giving an example of how to do both; since you asked for C# code that is equivalent to the Ruby code :)